# React - Overdoing it on "small components"

Tags: reactjs

So I've been working with React for several years now and lately people in my team started doing stuff like this:

```
const InputContainer = (props) => {
    const className = props.className;
    return <div {...{ className }}>
        {props.children}
    </div>;
};
```

This is basically just writing a `div` with a `class` and rendering the children.

So now my question: In my idea this is just overkill and is not usefull. It is creating components just for the sole purpose of using html tags. 
What do you think?

Why would this be useful when I can just do

```
<div>
    <p> ....
</div>
```

in one component?

I'm not against using small components but in my mind, this is just too much and is bloating everything instead of just using html.

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the reusability. If the piece of code your teammates are creating is reusable and can be used at multiple places then it's worth creating a component else for one time use, I don't think creating a component makes sense.

Comment: The above example certainly looks bloated. React is just a declarative way of writing complex widgets whose implementation is hidden. If it can achieved with simple html `(like above)`, then that should be used.

Comment: But if there are multiple nested divs, each having its owns styles and events, such as a `Card`, then that should be made into a component. So that the same can be reused without rewriting the bloat everywhere.

Comment: the only reason this was used was to have "defaultProps" defining one css class.
so `component.defaultProps = { classToSet: "classToSet" }`. Nothing more...

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is overdoing.
Are you sure it is not a joke? ;)
I am kidding, of course. Seriously, seems to me that it makes the code less readable and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: See my last comment up top.